# Autowired class spring context is null on VM with Selenium Cucumber

Tags: spring, selenium, gradle, cucumber, autowired

When running the locally via Eclipse or command prompt, the code is running fine. But when running it on Linux VM via Command the Autowiring is not working and d.sum throws null pointer exception.

command: gradle -Dcucumber.options="--tags @run" clean build

Added cucumber-spring dependency in gradle, but didn't worked.
Added @service tag but since in cucumber we use @cucumberoptions, it is throwing duplicate bean error

```
    @Component
    Class a()
    {
        public sum()
        {
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions ( )
    @ContextConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {<parent package>})
    Class Testrunnner() //main class 
    {
        @BeforeClass
        public setEnv()
        {
            SetEnv;
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////////    

    abc.feature //cucumber feature file

//////////////////////////////////

    Stepdef.java // cucumber stepdef
    {
        @Autowired 
        a d;

        public sumtwonumber()
        {
            d.sum();
        }
    }

///////////////////////////////////////
```

I expect that on running the code on VM via command, autowiring should work and sprint must get the context of class a

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace you get?